# avoiding "expression result unused" warning in a block

Tags: warnings, clang, objective-c-blocks

The following code is returning an expression unused warning on the assignment operation in the block. The code isn't very practical, but there is a lot more code in the excluded section and that code has to run on a particular queue.

```
__block NSNumber *pageId=nil;
dispatch_sync(_myDispatchQueue, ^{
    int val;
    //... code generates an int and puts it in val
    pageId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:val];
}];
//pageId used below
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: What version of clang are you using?  Can you provide a complete compilable testcase?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-value"
 pageId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:val];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 3):

### My Experimental Findings

Note I got this from Intrubidus, but I wanted additional information so after experimenting I recorded my findings here for the next guy.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-value"
pageId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:val];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Only applies to the area **between** the ignore and the pop.  "-Wunused-value" does not suppress unused variables.

This is how you would **suppress unused variables**:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
int i = 0;
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Also, **without the push and pop**, as shown:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-value"
pageId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:val];
```

The type of warning was ignored anywhere in that file **after** the #pragma.  This seems to only apply to the file in question.

Hope you found this useful,
    - Chase